# Do you need a Tableau Server license to be able to publish content from Desktop to the Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I have found conflicting responses to this question. Is a Server license necessary for publishing a report from Desktop to the server or will just a desktop license suffice? I understand without a Server license you can't access reports already on the Server, but for one-time publishing, is a Server license required?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Tableau Server license is not required according to this setup. This is a screen of the admin view when adding a user to a Tableau Server site. You need a user login but not a license.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Tableau Server 10.5, [the "Unlicensed (can publish)" site role has been removed](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/viewer-can-publish-and-unlicensed-can-publish-site-roles-removed-in-tableau-server-10-5), together with the "Viewer (can publish)" role.

Hence, the answer is now unfortunately **yes, you need a license** (if you use the user-based licensing model on your server).